# How to close previous window on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

I'm trying to close the previous window when I click the button to go to the next window. I'm not being able to do it. What's wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

def newwindow2():
    newwindow.destroy()
    newwindow2 = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow2.title('Nível da grama região 3')
    newwindow2.geometry('580x520')
    labl3 = Label(newwindow2, text='A foto do nível da grama na região 3 foi tirada:  \n', font=30).place(x=110, y=10)
    tk.Button(newwindow2, text='Fim').place(x=250, y=470)

def newwindow():
    janela1.destroy()
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Nível da grama região 2')
    newwindow.geometry('580x520')
    labl2 = Label(newwindow, text='A foto do nível da grama na região 2 foi tirada:  \n', font=30).place(x=110, y=10)
    tk.Button(newwindow, text='Próximo', command=newwindow2).place(x=250, y=470)


janela1 = tk.Tk()
janela1.title('Nível da grama região 1')
janela1.geometry("580x520")
labl1=Label(janela1, text='A foto do nível da grama na região 1 foi tirada: ',font=30).place(x=110, y=10)
tk.Button(janela1, text='Próximo', command=newwindow).place(x=250, y=470)

janela1.mainloop()
```

As you can see I'm trying to use .destroy() but it's not working. Any solutions? I'm just starting to learn Python so I'm aware this might be very simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see see several problems. The main one being that you can't call `newwindow.destroy()` because `newwindow` is a function not a `tk.Toplevel` widget. Another is the `janela1.destroy()` destroying itself, and it's the root window.

Instead of destroying windows, you can just `withdraw()` them. Here's code that I think does what you want:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def make_newwindow2():
#    newwindow.destroy()
    global newwindow2

    newwindow.withdraw()
    newwindow2 = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow2.title('Nível da grama região 3')
    newwindow2.geometry('580x520')
    labl3 = Label(newwindow2,
                  text='A foto do nível da grama na região 3 foi tirada:\n', font=30)
    labl3.place(x=110, y=10)
    tk.Button(newwindow2, text='Fim', command=root.quit).place(x=250, y=470)

def make_newwindow():
#    janela1.destroy()
    global newwindow

    root.withdraw()
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Nível da grama região 2')
    newwindow.geometry('580x520')
    labl2 = Label(newwindow,
                  text='A foto do nível da grama na região 2 foi tirada:\n', font=30)
    labl2.place(x=110, y=10)
    tk.Button(newwindow, text='Próximo', command=make_newwindow2).place(x=250, y=470)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Nível da grama região 1')
root.geometry("580x520")

labl1 = Label(root, text='A foto do nível da grama na região 1 foi tirada: ', font=30)
labl1.place(x=110, y=10)
tk.Button(root, text='Próximo', command=make_newwindow).place(x=250, y=470)

root.mainloop()
```

Something else I changed, even though it wasn't strictly necessary, was how you were assigning the result of calling `place()` to the names of a widgets. Since `place()` (and `pack()` and `grid()`) always return `None`, that's the value the variable will end up with — which is never what you'd want. You're getting away with it here, but only because those names aren't referenced again.