# Tkinter is returning same value for every radio button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am popping up a custom dialog box using Tkinter.
I am opening it from another Tkinter window.

```py
root = Tk()
class ListDialog:
    def __init__(self, names, prompt):
        self.names = names
        self.sub_root = Tk()
        self.sub_root.title("Intovex")
        self.sub_root.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
        self.myfont = Font(root=self.sub_root, family="Arial", size=8)
        self.sub_root.maxsize(320, 240)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-toolwindow", True)
        self.var = IntVar()
        label = Label(self.sub_root, text=prompt)
        label.pack(fill=X)
        c=1
        print(names)
        for i in names:
            print(i)
            r = Radiobutton(self.sub_root, text=i, variable=self.var, value=c, command=self.end)
            r.pack(anchor=W)
            c+=1
        self.var.set(1)
        button = Button(self.sub_root, command=self.endit, text="OK", bg = "#448DE0", fg="White", bd=0, width=12, pady=4, padx=4, height=1,font=self.myfont, highlightcolor="#A3C7F0")
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.choice = names[0]

    def end(self):
        ch = self.var.get()
        print(str(ch))
        self.choice = self.names[ch - 1]

    def endit(self):
        self.sub_root.destroy()

    def ask(self):
        self.sub_root.mainloop()
var2 = StringVar()
def get_choice():
    list = ListDialog(["Test1", "Test2"], "Testing")
    list.ask()
    var2.set(str(list.choice))

label = Label(root, text="", textvariable=var2)
button = Button(root, text="Test", command=get_choice)
label.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, it works when it is run alone by directly instantiating the class and invoking ask() method.
You may have seen that I have print statements everywhere in  the code(it is for debugging) and I found where isn't it working

- The print statement to print the `names` list parameter is printing the whole list correctly.
- Inside the for-loop also it prints the elements in the `names` list correctly
- When I click on a radio button it invokes the `end()` method. There it always prints the default value.

```py
root = Tk()
class ListDialog:
    def __init__(self, names, prompt):
        self.names = names
        self.sub_root = Tk()
        self.sub_root.title("Intovex")
        self.sub_root.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
        self.myfont = Font(root=self.sub_root, family="Arial", size=8)
        self.sub_root.maxsize(320, 240)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-toolwindow", True)
        self.var = IntVar()
        label = Label(self.sub_root, text=prompt)
        label.pack(fill=X)
        c=1
        print(names)
        for i in names:
            print(i)
            r = Radiobutton(self.sub_root, text=i, variable=self.var, value=c, command=self.end)
            r.pack(anchor=W)
            c+=1
        self.var.set(1)
        button = Button(self.sub_root, command=self.endit, text="OK", bg = "#448DE0", fg="White", bd=0, width=12, pady=4, padx=4, height=1,font=self.myfont, highlightcolor="#A3C7F0")
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.choice = names[0]

    def end(self):
        ch = self.var.get()
        print(str(ch))
        self.choice = self.names[ch - 1]

    def endit(self):
        self.sub_root.destroy()

    def ask(self):
        self.sub_root.mainloop()
list = ListDialog(["Test1", "Test2"], "Testing")
list.ask()
print(list.choice)
```

But it works if I open it as a TopLevel widget. But then the main window doesn't wait till the popup windows returns the value(choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code in the first snippet is because you're calling `Tk()` more that once within the tkinter application — it confuses the interface code and can cause a variety of problems, as you're finding out.

If you replace the call inside the `__init__()` method of the `ListDialog` class, with one to [`tk.Toplevel()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429194251id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) instead, then your code will start working.

I also streamlined the `for` loop that creates the `Radiobutton`s by changing it so to use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to automatically keep a count of the names. In conjunction with that, I made the initial value of the `IntVar` *zero* which is not one of the values that selecting one the radiobuttons will assign it. This is so when the `ListDialog` is first displayed, none of them will be selected. It also ensures that the `end()` callback function will get called whenever the user presses one of them, so your app will always be informed when that happens.

Note that, although I didn't change it, you shouldn't name a variable `list` because that hides the name of the built-in class by that name. In general you should avoid naming anything something that conflicts with an existing standard Python name.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

root = Tk()

class ListDialog:
    def __init__(self, names, prompt):
        self.names = names
#        self.sub_root = Tk()  # Wrong - don't call Tk() more than once.
        root.withdraw()  # Hide root window.
        self.sub_root = Toplevel()  # Create another top-level window.
        self.sub_root.title("Intovex")
#        self.sub_root.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")  # I don't have this file...
        self.myfont = Font(root=self.sub_root, family="Arial", size=8)
        self.sub_root.maxsize(320, 240)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.sub_root.wm_attributes("-toolwindow", True)
        self.var = IntVar(value=0)  # Define and init value to one *not* produced by btns.
        label = Label(self.sub_root, text=prompt)
        label.pack(fill=X)
        print(names)
        for c, name in enumerate(names, start=1):
            print(c)
            r = Radiobutton(self.sub_root, text=c, variable=self.var, value=c,
                            command=self.end)
            r.pack(anchor=W)

        button = Button(self.sub_root, command=self.endit, text="OK", bg = "#448DE0",
                        fg="White", bd=0, width=12, pady=4, padx=4, height=1,
                        font=self.myfont, highlightcolor="#A3C7F0")
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.choice = names[0]

    def end(self):
        ch = self.var.get()
        print(str(ch))
        self.choice = self.names[ch - 1]

    def endit(self):
        self.sub_root.destroy()
        root.deiconify()  # Reshow root window.

    def ask(self):
        self.sub_root.mainloop()

var2 = StringVar()

def get_choice():
    list = ListDialog(["Test1", "Test2"], "Testing")
    list.ask()
    var2.set(str(list.choice))

label = Label(root, text="", textvariable=var2)
button = Button(root, text="Test", command=get_choice)
label.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I use TopLevel the main window doesn't wait for the toplevel to complete.

Comment: i used TopLevel but the main window does not wait till the TopLr=evel window completes

Comment: I heard you the first time. You can call `root.withdraw()` to hide the main window. Read the documentation for `Toplevel()` in my answer.

Comment: Also see [How to close previous window on tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721295/how-to-close-previous-window-on-tkinter)

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to hide and re-show the main window.